# UWP/C# LaunchUriAsync Size issues

Tags: c#, uwp

Sorry for the mess of a title. 
Ive got the following C# script handling an Async Button press:

```
private async void CalcButton_ClickAsync(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)

    {
        await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri("calculator:"));
    }
```

Issue i have is that the calculator is loading up the exact same size as the main program window. I was wondering if there is a way to over-ride the sizing of the launched windows, i want the calculator to open up as small as possible really.

Come to think of it, i think every popup windows is doing this (save/open file dialogues) any thoughts/suggestions would be amazing

Answer (score 0):

You can request the desired remaining view.  Keep in mind that it is specifying the remaining view of the app that is launching the calculator... not the size of the calculator app.

link [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.system.launcheroptions.desiredremainingview)

```
private async void LaunchCalculator(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var options = new Windows.System.LauncherOptions();
    options.DesiredRemainingView = Windows.UI.ViewManagement.ViewSizePreference.UseMore;
    await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri("calculator:"), options);
}
```